# gVim how to disable hiragana input by default

Tags: vim, cjk

I have installed gVim7.4 on a windows 7 Japanese machine.
I have the problem that when I press "i" to go in insertion mode, I get an automatical and unwanted switch from romaji to hiragana insertion. Therefore I have everytime to manually press the ひらがな key to switch back to romaji mode. Otherwise I would write in hiragana and kanji.
Similarly when I press "/" to do a search, once again it switches automatically from romaji to hiragana. 
Do you know a way to set gVim with a romaji text insertion as default? How could I avoid these automatical switches into hiragana mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change default [IME](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/mbyte.html#IME) behaviour in Vim, put in your ~/.vimrc file

```
set iminsert=0 
set imsearch=-1
```

using `-1` for `imsearch` locks the search keymap to be the same as insert mode.

You can toggle IME option on and off using `<ctrl>+^`. To automatically disable Japanese IME when leaving insert mode you can use

```
inoremap <ESC> <ESC>:set iminsert=0<CR>
```

More on these

```
:h iminsert
:h imsearch
:h i_CTRL-^
```

---

Addition: It can be handy to change the colour of your cursor depending on the settings of IME

```
if has('multi_byte_ime')
    highlight Cursor guifg=NONE guibg=Green
    highlight CursorIM guifg=NONE guibg=Purple
endif
```

I found it in

```
:h CursorIM
```

Comment: +1 - Interesting. I was going to suggest switching from the desktop to an English input method, but your solution is 11 times better (at least).